# Umbraco rewrite rules using UrlRewritingNet

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco, urlrewriter.net

I'm trying to setup some rewrite rules for a new Umbraco website we have. I need to redirect from the previous website Url's to the new location within Umbraco, i.e:

http://www.somedomain.com/index.php/en/cms/59_about+energy+management

http://www.somedomain.com/energy-management.aspx

This is the rule I have at the moment:

```
<add name="1"
  virtualUrl="^~/index.php/en/cms/59_about+energy+management"
  destinationUrl="~/energy-management.aspx"
  ignoreCase="true"
  redirect="Application" />
```

I've managed to get the home.aspx to redirect back to the root location, but nothing I do seems to work for the old Url's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is IIS and/or Umbraco handling the .php extension?   If not then it will never get to these rules.